# Percentage of Total per Product group in qlikview

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I have a table which looks like this:

```
Group Value Month
A     100   1
A     150   2
B     50    1
B     100   2
```

what is the right expression to have a formula in qlikview to have this later in a lineplot, where the x-axis is the month , the y-values are the values in % of the total per month and the groups are the groups.

Right now I have:

```
Sum(Value)/Sum(total <Value> [Month])
```

which is not working.

Comment: Other way around? Sum(Value)/Sum(total <Month> Value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sum(Value)/sum(total <Month> Value)
```

You want to group the denominator by Month not add up the months per Value

[image]

Comment: somehow this is not working for a 'Date.YearMonth' column, the visualization is empty?

Comment: forget it, it is: `Datum.autoCalendar.YearMonth`